# Access Values of Cell Array deeply nested within Structure Array

Tags: data-structures, octave, cell-array

I have a nested structure_array/cell_array/structure_array of character values which is the result of a web query which returns a converted JSON object, the needed numeric value(s) of which I can access in loops thus:

```
for ix = 1 : size( S.orderBook.buckets , 2 )
 if ( str2double( S.orderBook.buckets{ ix }.price ) >= str2double( S.orderBook.price ) )
  mid_ix = ix ;  
  break ;
 endif
endfor
```

The above loop gets the index, mid_ix, of the cell in the middle of the region of interest, and

```
orderbook_begin_ix = mid_ix - 20 ; orderbook_end_ix = mid_ix + 20 ;

jj = 0 ;
for ix = orderbook_begin_ix : orderbook_end_ix
 jj = jj + 1 ;
 new_orderbook_data( 1 , jj ) = str2double( S.orderBook.buckets{ ix }.longCountPercent ) ;
endfor
```

this second loop fills the pre-initialised matrix, new_orderbook_data, with the values of interest.

However, I was wondering whether there is a quicker/more elegant way of getting these values? At the moment, as can be seen above, I am having to run a "look up" for loop that encloses an "if statement" to get in the ballpark of the required numeric values, and then run a second for loop in the region of the ballpark to extract these required values.

Note: cross posted at [Octave forum](https://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/Access-Values-of-Cell-Array-deeply-nested-within-Structure-Array-td4696710.html)

Comment: The numbers being stored as strings makes them hard to work with. I would recommend to convert those to numbers first. Once that is done, you can use vectorized code for the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have solved this by using the syntax below:

```
prices = cellfun( @str2double , { [ S.orderBook.buckets{:} ].price } ) ;
```

which gives me a matrix "prices" to which I can further apply vectorised code.

Explanation:-

1. the { : } extracts the prices from the cell array into a comma
   separated list,
2. the enclosing [ ] puts this list into a structure array,
3. the [ ].price extracts just the prices which are then put back into a
   cell array with the outermost enclosing { }
4. and then the string values are converted to numeric by applying the
   cellfun to this prices cell array and
5. are finally assigned to the "prices" matrix.